# Guardar cada fila en un array al enviar un formulario

Tags: php, sql, formularios

Estoy haciendo un formulario que saca información de una base de datos mysql y php la muestra en un formulario con checkboxes, mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Cómo guardo cada fila seleccionada en un array?

Este es el codigo que crea cada fila del formulario:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['producto'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['precio'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='name". $row['ID'] ."' value=". $row['ID'] ."></td>"; 
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='enviar' value='enviar'>";
echo "</form>"; `
```

Comment: Cuéntanos por favor cuáles son los valores que quieres incluir en el array: ¿solo los valores de los checkbox seleccionados?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes poner el nombre al checkbox como un arreglo

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='name[]`introducir el código aquí`". $row['ID'] ."' value=". $row['ID'] ."></td>";
```

y en tu archivo php donde proceses la información recibirás un arreglo con todos los checkbox seleccionados

```
 $datos = $_POST["name"];

foreach($datos as $selected){
    echo $selected."</br>";
}
```